# C++ Using a lambda in find_if to find pair variables

Tags: c++, vector, lambda, find, std-pair

So I'm having trouble understanding lambdas and how they work, specifically if i have a

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> storage;
```

and want to write a function that looks like

```
bool VNS::remove(const std::string& host) {
   auto end = storage.end();
   auto found = find_if (storage.begin(), end, [host](pair<string,int> curr)     {return curr.first == host; });
```

i.e I want to find a host in a vector of pairs , where hostname is stored in the first part of the pair. How do I properly specify whats in the lambda function to be able to do this?

Regards.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there?

Comment: HostName is specified in a file as 
using HostName = std::string;

Right sorry, this seemed to work. How weird. Apparently the compile was complaining about my next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this method works, so there's that. I managed to misinterpret my compiler's output into thinking the lambda function was at fault, but this seems to be one way of making it work.